# rhythmbox fails to run plugin "plugin loader 'python' was not found"

Tags: 18.04, rhythmbox, plugins

I tried to install a "somewhat" old [rb-open-folder](https://github.com/luqmana/rhythmbox-plugins/tree/master/rb-open-folder) plugin to rhythmbox.

I copied the files to `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/open-folder/` as instructed

When I try to enable the plugin, rhythmbox shows error. If I put my mouse over the addon entry, this appears:

> plugin loader 'python' was not found

I have both python and python3 installed.

Comment: Issue [here](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153).

Comment: @SayanDey Actually, it's [the last comment that matters](https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153#issuecomment-735338099). That's what I wrote as the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, Rhythmbox plugins run using python3.

First confirm whether `python -V` returns version 2 or 3. Here are examples of them:

1. Python 3.6.9
2. Python 2.7.17

If you have the 1st case, I don't have a solution for you.

However, if you have the 2nd case (python 2), then you can try the following steps:

1. Locate the manifest file (You probably can find it like this: `~/.local/share/rhythmbox/plugins/open-folder/*.plugin`)
2. Edit the `loader=` line to python3. For example:
3. `Loader=python3`
4. Try again

See if that works for you

Part of the source: https://github.com/gmate/gmate/issues/153#issuecomment-735338099